# Recommendations for small stocks indicator?

Tags: software-recommendation, finance

I would like to know in one glance the value of some stocks and currencies. What kind of indicator would you advice to me?

I guess an equivalent of indicators, like a widget or whatever, should be fine too. I remember there was such a possibility on older versions of Ubuntu with GNOME 2, with a notification icon.

Comment: I disagree - this is *not* too localized.  Please re-open.

Comment: Take a look at [indicator-stocks](http://askubuntu.com/a/381224/117559).

Comment: Indicator-stocks does the job, thank you for developing it!

Comment: IMO, @NathanJ.Brauer is right. We should reopen this, and make an answer from the comment that currently answers this question. Then this will better help others, and it will be one less "too localized" question for high-rep users to sift through when deciding which closed questions merit deletion.

Comment: @EliahKagan someone really is interested in answering *this* question? There's SR already, and they answer this kind of questions. Also, this only got 141 views in 3 years, is not that relevant to Ubuntu users. Also that *answer* is pointing to [another question](http://askubuntu.com/q/30334/169736) so, no information is lost.

Comment: Correction 2 years

Comment: @Braiam We *already have an answer*. It's posted as a comment. I'd be happy to make a CW answer out of it if/when this is reopened, and I can try to include more info on indicator-stocks than is currently in the hisorical-interest indicators big list question. (Also, for half that 2 years it's been less visible due to closure.) There's one area where we may agree: I don't think it's extremely important that this be reopened. I'm not trying to turn this pretty minor question into a *cause celebre*. I'm just trying to do what I think is most helpful and appropriate with it.

Comment: @EliahKagan just FYI, closed questions do appear in google.

Comment: @Braiam That's true, they do. Sorry if what I said had the effect of suggesting otherwise. However, they don't come up on the front page of our site very often. And I think being closed with "no answers" makes it harder for people to recognize that there is actually a solution here. Furthermore, when a question is on-topic, there's no requirement that it be of interest to a large fraction of the community. Back when we had the "too localized" close reason, its correct use was for questions that would *probably never be relevant to anyone else* (or, for time-localized questions, ever again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the OP pointed in [his comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95442/recommendations-for-small-stocks-indicator#comment487317_95442), [**indicator-stocks**](https://launchpad.net/~ce3a/+archive/indicator-stocks) does the job. To install it, run the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ce3a/indicator-stocks
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-stocks
```

Answer (score 0):

GNOME extension [Stocks Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1422/stocks-extension/) is a handy solution I found on Ubuntu 20.04 that can achieve the requirement.

I installed the extension from the [GNOME Shell integration](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/) of a web browser.